# \overset alignment for inverse inverse

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath, overset

I am trying to use \overset to get the following output:

[image]

But what I get with my code

```
 $ (\overset{\Xi}{F^{-1}})_{\widetilde{D}}^{D}$
```

[image]

I would like to have \Xi alligned right over the F.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to make four changes.

- Most importantly, change

  ```
  \overset{\Xi}{F^{-1}}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \overset{\Xi}{F}^{-1}
  ```

  Put differently, the second argument of `\overset` has to be `F`, not `F^{-1}`.
- Insert an empty math atom between `\overset{\Xi}{F}` and `^{-1}`, as otherwise the inverse-symbol will be placed much too high.
- (Optional) Change `\Xi` to `\scriptscriptstyle\Xi` to reduce the size of `\Xi`. (The default math style for the first argument of `\overset` is `\scriptstyle`; `\scriptscriptstyle` makes for a 30% linear reduction.)
- Surround `(\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\Xi}{F}{}^{-1})^{D}` with curly  braces and follow it with `_{\widetilde{D}}` in order to get the desired horizontal offset of the superscript and subscript terms. Optionally, change `_{\widetilde{D}}` to `_{\!\widetilde{D}}` to reduce the horizontal separation a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \overset macro
\begin{document}
$(\overset{\Xi}{F^{-1}})_{\widetilde{D}}^{D}$ vs.\
${(\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\,\Xi}{F}{}^{-1})^{D}}_{\!\widetilde{D}}$
\end{document}
```